# tempdb is not growing under Read Committed Snapshot Isolation

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

In order to remedy deadlocks (introduced by indexed view), I attempted to utilize RCSI in sql server. I engaged this mode by:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
```

and verified that it is set by:

```
DBCC useroptions  

SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

I have 8 tempdbs in my database and they are set to auto grow by 64 MB. After ingesting thousands of records I do not see any growth in tempdbs. Based on documentation the RCSI heavily uses tempdb and increases its size considerably. I expected to see some increase in tempdb. Trace 1117, 1118 are also ON. But there is no increase in tempdb size. I have not turned on Allow Snap Shot Isolation for Tempddb database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Based on documentation the RCSI heavily uses tempdb and increases its size considerably.

There's a lot of baseless worry about RCSI.  And INSERTs only create row versions if there is a trigger on the table.

Answer (score 1):

From [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server)

> When the SNAPSHOT isolation level is enabled, each time a row is updated, the SQL Server Database Engine stores a copy of the original row in tempdb, and adds a transaction sequence number to the row.

This means that if you are updating one row, one row will be put in TempDB, if you are altering or updating an entire table the entire table will be put in TempDB. So it is entirely possible that your specific work load does not require large amounts of data to be versioned in TempDB. I've needed to increase the size of TempDB considerably (or turned off RSCI) during large updates to avoid this problem.

This [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5014/what-risks-are-there-if-we-enable-read-committed-snapshot-in-sql-server) also discusses many things to consider when using TempDB.